# Enumerable disjoint subsets whose union is equal to the union of the sets

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

I'm given that two sets, $A$ and $B$ are enumerable. I have to show that there exist subsets $A \supset C$ and $B \supset D$ ($C$ and $D$ also enumerable) such that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint and $A\cup B = C \cup D$. I was thinking to take $A=B=\{0,1\}$ and define $C=\{n : f(n)=1\}$, $D=\{n: f(n)=0\}$. 
Do you think this is right?

Comment: You need to show that for *every* $A,B$ there exist sets $C,D$. I don't see where $f$ is coming from - it doesn't appear in your statement of the problem.

Comment: Once you understand what the question is actually asking, I doubt that you will have trouble solving it.

Comment: Since f is enumerable, there exist some f that enumerates the elements of C and D, which are subsets of A and B, respectively. How could I define A and B, then? To be infinite or finite sets?

Comment: You don't define $A,B$. You are *given* $A,B$. The sets you have to come up with are $C,D$.

Comment: I could extend C and D to be C={0,1,2,...,i} and D={i+1,i+2,...,n}, and since C and D are enumerable, their union is enumerable. Is it better now?

Comment: I suggest contacting a TA. It seems you are missing some basic definitions, and it is hard to diagnose this any further on this platform.

Comment: This isn't for us; it belongs in math.SE.

Comment: What do you mean by *enumerable*? Do you mean *recursively enumerable*, that is, enumerable by a Turing machine?

Comment: @RickDecker Properties of recursively enumerable sets seems like a CS question, to me. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: @DavidRicherby. Because nowhere does the OP use the word "recursively".

Comment: @RickDecker You suggest elsewhere that "enumerable" on its own means "countable". I've never heard that but, if it is what the asker means, I agree that the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that *enumerable* means *recursively enumerable*.

Here is an enumerator for $C$:

- Run enumerators for $A,B$ in parallel.
- Whenever the enumerator for $A$ outputs a word, check whether the word has already been enumerated by the enumerator for $B$; if it hasn't, output it and continue.

The enumerator for $D$ is defined symmetrically.

Comment: So the idea is to assign the element from the intersection to the side whose enumerator gets there first. If this construction is to define unique $C$, $D$, the specific implementation of "run in parallel" matters (alongside the choice of the enumerators for $A$, $B$).

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as you do it in exactly the same way for both $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Right. Just saying, $C$ and $D$ will differ if you change the details of the construction, but all have the required properties. If $A \cap B$ is infinite, it seems plausible that there are infinitely many such $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the fact that a subset of an enumerable set is enumerable? If you can, then you could choose $C=A$ and $D=B\setminus A$ (set difference). Then $C$ and $D$ are enumerable and it's easy to show that $A\cup B=C\cup D$.

Comment: Assuming the OP means *recursively* enumerable, this is wrong.

Comment: @Raphael. I made no such assumption.

Comment: This answer is extremely doubtful. It seems reasonable (if not certain) to assume that *enumerable* means *recursively enumerable* in this context, since this site is for computer science.

Comment: "a subset of [a recursively] enumerable set is [recursively] enumerable" -- this is a wrong statement, as I'm sure we can agree.

Comment: It seems at least as reasonable to interpret "enumerable" as "countable". The OP's responses support that.